# Googletest does not accept temporary object in EXPECT_THROW

Tags: c++, g++, googletest

I have a class that has no default constructor, but the constructor may throw. I was wanting to have a test like:

```
EXPECT_THROW(MyClass(param), std::runtime_error);
```

But the compiler, `g++`, complains that there is no default constructor for `MyClass`. However, the following...

```
EXPECT_THROW(MyClass foo(param), std::runtime_error);
```

...works, and the test passes as expected.  Why though won't Googletest accept the temporary object?

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass(std::string const& filename);
  //...
};
```

Interestingly enough, I had refactored my test to not have the filename in a separate variable, and when asked to check I found the following works:

```
EXPECT_THROW(MyClass("somefilename"), std::runtime_error);
```

However the following doesn't:

```
std::string filename("somefilename");
EXPECT_THROW(MyClass(filename), std::runtime_error);
```

Answer (score 17):

If you're hit with the "most vexing parse", the cure is often uniform initialization:

```
EXPECT_THROW(MyClass{param}, std::runtime_error);
```

(assuming your compiler understands C++11).

Comment: Note that if MyClass takes more than 1 parameter, an extra set of parenthesis is needed because EXPECT_THROW is a macro: `EXPECT_THROW((MyClass{param1, param2}), std::runtime_error);`

Answer (score 8):

When dealing with macros, ultimate tool is analyzing expanded macro:

In your case (and for gtest 1.6):

```
EXPECT_THROW(MyClass(filename), std::runtime_error);
```

Expands to:

```
...
    bool gtest_caught_expected = false; \
    try { \
      if (::testing::internal::AlwaysTrue()) { MyClass(filename); }; \
    } \
    catch (std::runtime_error const&) { \
      gtest_caught_expected = true; \
    } \
    catch (...) { \
      gtest_msg.value = \
          "Expected: " "MyClass(filename)" " throws an exception of type " \
          "std::runtime_error" ".\n  Actual: it throws a different type."; \
      goto gtest_label_testthrow_88; \
    } \
    if (!gtest_caught_expected) { \
      gtest_msg.value = \
          "Expected: " "MyClass(filename)" " throws an exception of type " \
          "std::runtime_error" ".\n  Actual: it throws nothing."; \
      goto gtest_label_testthrow_88; \
    } \
...
```

As you can see, argument to `EXPECT_THROW` is not object, but expression to be evaluated further, within GTEST provided valid try/catch block.

So anything you pass to it, must be able to evaluate as expression within nested scope of current scope. In your case:

```
MyClass(filename)
```

Is ambiguous, but according to Most vexing parse rule, declaration interpretation is preferred, so you end up with:

```
MyClass filename
```

So you are creating variable named filename of class MyClass - and hence error about missing constructor.

This mechanism is not triggered if you use literal string:

```
MyClass("some string")
```

Becouse following would be invalid (and there is no ambiguity):

```
MyClass "some string"
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you give more information?  I constructed an example which works fine with a class that only has a one argument constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

#include "gtest/gtest.h"

class m {
    public:
        m(std::string a) {std::cout << "one argument constructor" << std::endl;}
};

int main() {
    EXPECT_THROW(m("hat"), std::runtime_error);
}
```

Output:

```
one argument constructor
gtt.cc:12: Failure
Expected: m("hat") throws an exception of type std::runtime_error.
Actual: it throws nothing.
```

**EDIT**
I do not claim to be an expert on the arcane inner-workings of the C/C++ pre-processor, but I think this has to do with the rules followed when evaluating expressions, in particular, in the land of the pre-processor, parentheses are king.  When the pre-processor evaluates `MyClass(filename)` it first evaluates filename which produces a temporary value which is immediately discarded, it then evaluates `MyClass()`.  Calling `MyClass("filename")` causes the pre-processor to actually copy the literal string into the expression.  One way around this problem is to call `EXPECT_THROW((MyClass(filename)), std::runtime_error)`, i.e. use a set of enclosing parentheses around your statement.

Comment: Ha... isn't that weird.  I went to reproduce it, and I found that my refactoring caused it not to happen.  However reversing my refactoring and I found the error.  I'll add the details above.

Comment: Added tentative answer in my post